# Discord bot prints "None" on server but desired output on terminal

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to build a discord bot that outputs info on different stocks. When using the command `AAPL` on the server I have my bot in, the bot outputs the message `None`. However, on the terminal which I'm running my code on, the output is

```
      Company Symbol    Weight   Price   Chg     % Chg
0  Apple Inc.   AAPL  6.888732  177.65 -1.73  (-0.96%)
```

So there's clearly no problems with the actual info, as it's printed, but it's not displayed on my discord server (see image for reference). Have I missed something?
[image]

I also included my code if it helps:

```py
# bot.py
import os
import SandPwebscraper as stocks

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    )

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    

    if message.content == 'AAPL':
        response = stocks.appletest()
        messageToSend = str(response)
        await message.channel.send(messageToSend)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Are DISCORD_TOKEN and DISCORD_GUILD properly set in the server environment?

Comment: Where are you printing the response? If you add `print(messageToSend)` does it appear correct in the console?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yeah I believe so, I didn't get any connection errors regarding the token or guild

Comment: @Jesse Also interestingly, after the desired stock info message, the message `None` is also printed on the terminal...